# Finding a Group isomorphism G

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_isomorphism), Isomorphism:

> Given two groups $(G, ∗)$ and $(H, {\displaystyle \odot })$, a group isomorphism from $(G, ∗)$ to $(H, {\displaystyle \odot })$ is a bijective group homomorphism from $G$ to $H$. Spelled out, this means that a group isomorphism is a bijective function ${\displaystyle f:G\rightarrow H}$ such that for all $u$ and $v$ in $G$ it holds that
>
> $${\displaystyle f(u*v)=f(u)\odot f(v)}$$

---

#### Somewhere, I found this example:

Consider the group $G$ of real numbers under multiplication.

Let, $$G'=G \space \space \text{and} \space \space f(x)=2x \space\space\space\space \forall x \in G$$
Now, $f: G→G'$ is an isomorphism

Since, $$f(x_1*x_2)=\color{red}{f(2(x_1*x_2))=f(2(x_1\times x_2))=2\times2(x_1\times x_2)}=4x_1x_2$$

Now, $$f(x_1)=2x_1 \space\space f(x_2)=2x_2 →f(x_1)*f(x_2)=4x_1*x_2$$

Therefore,
$$f(x_1*x_2)=f(x_1)*f(x_2)$$
It can be easily verified that $f(x) = 2x$ is both one to one and onto function from $G$ to $G'$.

Hence, $f(x)=2x$ is an isomorphism from $G$ to $G'$.

> I understood except red colored line:
>
> How we are taking $2$ and replacing $*$ to $\times$ operator. Again, taking $2$, after removing $f$. Could you please explain it ?

---

---

#### Related question:

Also notice that $f(x) = x^3$ is only a homomorphisms, but not isomorphism from $G$ to $G'$, since it is neither one to one nor onto from $G$ to $G'$.

> In this $f(x) = x^3$, if it is neither one to one (i.e., monomorphism) nor onto (i.e., epicmorphism) from $G$ to $G'$, so can not be bijection (i.e., isomorphims); then,
>
> How is it even Homomorphims ? Could you please explain it?
>   Could you please provide proof that $f(x) = x^3$ is neither one to one nor onto from $G$ to $G'$.

Comment: Well, $x^3$ needs $G$ to be Abelian in order to be a group homomorphism.

Comment: The real numbers do not form a group under multiplication. Perhaps you meant addition?

Comment: @DerekHolt, inverse does not exist for element $0$ under multiplication in set of real number. It should be typo in that book. Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasShelby, does it mean $1→1$ not exist, but $f: 1→2$.

Comment: @10 Yes, $1$ is mapped to $2$, instead of  $1$ here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

f is not an isomorphism of the multiplicative group of reals because
2×3×5 = f(3×5), while f(3)×(5) = 2×3×2×5 = 2×f(3×5).
Exercise.  Show f is an isomorphism of the additive group of reals

Comment: Agreed. Thanks. Any hint about $x^3$.

Comment: It is a multiplicative isomorphism.